# ListView vs RecyclerView when working with SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I know **RecyclerView** is more *flexible* and *fast* than **ListView**, but when it comes to "Working with **SQLite Database**" is it good to use RecyclerView instead of Listview?

I think the ListView gives much more control over the `Cursor`, the `Adapter`, the data and on top of all it is much easier to implement than RecyclerView.
So, does it make sense to use RecyclerView for just minor performance improvement?

Comment: If you don't need any of the features that RecyclerView offers, I don't see the problem with using ListView instead. However it probably is good practice to use RecyclerView as it seems that Google wants this to be the future of lists/grids and what they will be updating with new features and possibly deprecating ListViews and GridViews.

Comment: I feel the Recyclerview gives you more control and you know why and how everything happens. With the listview it manages too much. Its also easy to add a lot of custom views and functionality to a recyclerview plus the recyclerview is really decoupled.

Comment: I think that use of RecyclerView now is justified not only by the performance improvement - I would say that it is much more flexible in terms of Views positioning and since Google recommends to use it now -  there is a probability that in future all the descendants of AdapterView will be deprecated

Comment: I agree with all of you. Perhaps Google just need to make RecyclerView API a little easier to implement so that we don't need to write a lot of code just for registering a "Click" on recyclerview item. Anyways thanks for your reply, i will be using RecyclerView henceforth. :)